# How can I specify .env file to use for my dev server when running Cypress tests?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, cypress

How can I specify which `.env` file to use for my dev server when running Cypress tests? These are system level env vars not Cypress test env vars.

I have an env file that I want to use for my server when running cypress tests: `.env.local.cypress`

In my `package.json` file I have:

```json
"dev-server": "nodemon --delay 5ms -e ts,tsx --watch ./src -x ts-node --transpile-only ./src/server",
"cy:run": "cypress run",
"test:e2e:local": "dotenv -e .env.local.cypress -- start-server-and-test dev-server http://localhost:3000 cy:run"
```

When I run `test:e2e:local` the server starts with the correct env vars but the tests do not. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pick up any global env variables in `cypress.config.js` in a couple of ways.

**Via dotenv CLI (as per your example)**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...process.env,                 // add all process env var here
        ...config.env                   // plus any command line overrides
      }
      return config     
    },
  },
})
```

That gives you ***everything currently defined*** at system level, including those added via dotenv CLI.

You can just add specific vars:

```js
config.env = {
  abc: process.env.abc,
  ...config.env                  
}
```

**Via local dotenv install**

Or you can use the `dotenv` package locally to load just the specific env file inside `cypress.config.js`

```js
npm install dotenv --save
```

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

const local = require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.local.cypress' })

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...local.parsed,
        ...config.env               
      }
      return config     
    },
  },
})
```